# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

    // *** here  *** 
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, 
               hasFocus, row, col); 

    // Formatting here
    return c;
}
```

I'm getting an error in the indicated line.  It says "cannot find symbol" but I can't realize what the real problem is.

---

**Updated**

@martinusadyh

I'm afraid the class is too big so it doesn't allow me to paste it here.

@ Hovercraft Full Of Eels

here's the error in Netbeans
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fv3.jpg

@Henery

It's not my class. I'm only implementing an interface method.

Comment: Please show the actual text of the error message in  your post above. Does it say more than "cannot find symbol"? Every bit of information is essential.

Comment: And you can't **bold** posted code.

Comment: Did you make sure that your super class contain the exact method getTableCellRendererComponent with the same signature?

Comment: @Maxi Dee: can you paste your full source code ? I mean, we need to know which class you implemented or extend.

Comment: @martinusadyh

I'm afraid the class it's too big so it doesnt allow me to paste it here.

Comment: @martinusadyh

I'm afraid the class it's too big so it doesnt allow me to paste it here.

Comment: PLEASE! Do me (and yourself) a favour and put the font of NetBeans to something **Monospaced**...

Comment: In which class this method getTableCellRendererComponent() is implemented? or at least say which class you are extending if such is a case?

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels

here's the error in Netbeans

h t t p : / / i. stack.i mgur.com/R4fv3.jpg

Comment: @martinusadyh done, here's the code h t t p://pastebin.com/m7QnkUMC its too big to paste it here.

Comment: @MaxiDee: that's why you shouldn't try to have a class do too much. Your class extends JPanel and implements TableCellRenderer, but JPanel doesn't have the super method. Perhaps you want your class to extend DefaultTableCellRenderer.

Comment: @MaxiDee you get error because `super` in your method calling JPanel class, and JPanel don't have method `getTableCellRendererComponent()`. If you want to do some custom rendering to your JTable, why you do not implemented in your method in this class ? Why you must call `super` ???

Answer (score 3):

> It's not mine that class, i'm only implementing an interface's method.

Then your parent class `super` is `Object` and has no method `getTableCellRendererComponent`. You either have to extend a suitable class or get along without calling non-existing methods.

Comment: Makes sense -- but then why wouldn't there be an error at the @Override annotation? The `getTableCellRendererComponent` method certainly doesn't override a method of Object.

Comment: If he is using Java6 @Hovercraft, the `Override` could be for the interface method so there is not a super method with the same name.

Comment: @A.H.: Aha and exactly! That's what was tripping me up. Great thoughts and 1+.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, i'm using java 7

Comment: @MaxiDee: what does using Java 7 have to do with the price of tea in China?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i know i know

Comment: @Gray im using java 7, i dont think that this is important

Comment: @gray when I used the code in answer 2, I realized that I was calling a super method, when the class wasn't inheriting nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `extends DefaultTableCellRenderer` instead of `implements TableCellRenderer`.

---

**Note**: `DefaultTableCellRenderer` its method `getTableCellRendererComponent` returns `this`. This means that it's enough to call the `super.getTableCellRendererComponent();` without assigning it to a local variable. Because the local variable equals `this`. Maybe my explanation is too difficult: example.

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col); 

        // Formatting here
        setIcon(myCustomIcon);
        setText(myCustomText);

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: i cant extend DefaultTableCellRenderer because im already extending JPanel to show the table!

Comment: @MaxiDee: then it's obvious you can't call the super method. Solution: don't try to do this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels to sum up, then, I'll have to try painting the cells using other tecniques.. thx!!

Comment: @MaxiDee: No, you have to create a **new** class. (Which means a new `.java` file). Then use an instance of that class as cell renderer for your table.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux i'll try creating a new class, see how can I make it work, then I tell you. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux sorry for me asking so much, but where i should instance the class extending DefaultTableCellRenderer? because i try to call the getTableCellRendererComponent method but it wont work

Comment: `myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());`